# Using boost::assign::list_of with boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

Given:

```
typedef boost::variant<std::vector<int8>, std::vector<std::string> > Container;
```

How can I initialize `c` as a one liner?

```
std::vector<std::string> v = boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("stringValue");
Container c(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do - explicitly cast the list_of result to the type you want the variant to store:

```
Container c(vector<string>(list_of<string>("stringValue")));
```

Or even better - use C++11:

```
Container c{ vector<string> {"stringValue1", "stringValue2"}};
```

Comment: How would one initialize the container with `std::vector<int8>` and `std::vector<std::string>` at the same time?

Comment: @Olumide one wouldn't. Variants are either-or containers, you can't fit both.